# How to load full angular app AFTER login?

Tags: angularjs, performance, optimization

I'm building a fairly large single page angular app that will likely end up being 5mb+ when complete.  The app is only used for users logged into the site.

At the same time I have a static landing page that only needs jquery and a couple small scripts to load.

I would rather not load the angular app on this landing page to avoid unnecessary network traffic.  What is the best way to architect the site with these constraints? Ideally keeping the landing page lightweight as possible

Comment: The simplest solution is to put the angular app in a different directory and then just put a link from the landing page to the angular app. If you want to put the login on the landing then you would implement the login using jQuery and then change the url using `document.location` to the spa.